# Erratic (seemingly random) behavior of seek() and split() in python

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as data_file:
   data_file.readline() #skipping lines of texts
   data_file.readline()
   data_file.readline() #skipping lines of texts
   data_file.readline()
   data_file.readline() #skipping lines of texts
   data_file.readline() #skipping lines of texts
   data_file.readline() #skipping lines of texts
   data_file.readline() #skipping lines of texts
   data_file.readline() #skipping lines of texts
   while True:
       print "#"
       pos=data_file.tell()
       next_mol=data_file.readline().split()
       print next_mol
       data_file.seek(pos)
       print data_file.readline().split()
```

here sys.argv[1] is the name of text file, which contains the following data:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
31500000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
28244
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0.706774 63.6072
1.77317 62.6918
-4.27518 67.4572
ITEM: ATOMS id type x y z 
1 1 8.07271 20.6394 38.953 
2 1 7.45444 20.2706 37.5682 
3 1 7.94593 21.3438 36.5822 
4 2 8.88701 22.2414 37.422 
5 6 8.97587 21.7898 38.6976 
6 7 9.51512 23.1098 36.8675 
7 1 9.83459 22.2787 39.7728 
8 3 8.54346 19.7726 39.3733 
9 3 7.3188 20.9572 39.6053 
10 3 6.33686 20.2798 37.6457 
11 3 7.62824 19.2464 37.1935 
12 3 7.14438 21.9616 36.2781 
13 3 8.4454 20.9589 35.6742 
14 3 9.51704 23.2023 40.2712 
15 3 10.839 22.4705 39.342 
16 3 9.84061 21.5031 40.5668
```

gives me following output:

```
#
['1', '1', '8.07271', '20.6394', '38.953']
['71', '20.6394', '38.953']
#
['2', '1', '7.45444', '20.2706', '37.5682']
['1', '7.45444', '20.2706', '37.5682']
#
['3', '1', '7.94593', '21.3438', '36.5822']
['1', '7.94593', '21.3438', '36.5822']
#
['4', '2', '8.88701', '22.2414', '37.422']
['2', '8.88701', '22.2414', '37.422']
#
['5', '6', '8.97587', '21.7898', '38.6976']
['6', '8.97587', '21.7898', '38.6976']
#
['6', '7', '9.51512', '23.1098', '36.8675']
['7', '9.51512', '23.1098', '36.8675']
#
['7', '1', '9.83459', '22.2787', '39.7728']
['1', '9.83459', '22.2787', '39.7728']
#
['8', '3', '8.54346', '19.7726', '39.3733']
['3', '8.54346', '19.7726', '39.3733']
#
['9', '3', '7.3188', '20.9572', '39.6053']
['3', '7.3188', '20.9572', '39.6053']
#
['10', '3', '6.33686', '20.2798', '37.6457']
['0', '3', '6.33686', '20.2798', '37.6457']
```

I was expecting both strings between '#' to be same. Am i missing something here?

Comment: `file.readline()` almost certainly uses a buffer; the file position won't be right after the last produced newline, it'll be after the read-ahead buffer used to find newlines.

Comment: any better alternatives? or alternatives for reading next line and revert back to previous positions?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why not just store already-read lines instead?

Comment: all 16 lines belong to a group A (a molecule) there is another group in file say group B. Idea was to read next line and see if that belong to group A, in which case read next 16 lines, else it is of group B so skip next 3 lines. repeat this pattern till EOF is reached. but seek() and readline as shown here is truncating previous line. This was the easiest way that came to mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.readline()` uses a *read-ahead buffer* to find newlines, so it can return you a neat line that ends in `\n`. The alternative is to read byte by byte until a newline is found, which would be extremely inefficient.

As such, your first `file.readline()` reads in a chunk of information from the file, parses out the first line and returns that. Then a next call to `file.readline()` may well be able to give you the next line from the buffer alone, etc.

By the time you get to your `while` loop, the read-ahead buffer has been filled with every thing up to `1 1 8.072` (the first bytes after the `ITEM: ATOMS id type x y z` line). The next `file.readline()` call then reads in more buffer to find another newline, moving the file position to after the initial `2` on the next line, etc.

You can't reliably get the right file position from a file *and* use `file.readline()` calls; you'd have to take into account the number of lines read, the actual buffer size, and the style of line separators used in the file. Your problem can almost certainly be solved in different ways, like storing the already read lines in a queue or stack of some sort, for use in later iterations of your loop.